# KeePassX Auto-Type in no longer operational

Tags: keepass, keepassx

In KeePassX the auto-type feature was working fine, until few days ago when it stopped.

I download a lot of libraries and programs and delete them, so most likely something affected it and when I tried to remove and then reinstall it, it wouldn't.

Has anyone experienced this problem ?

I use Ubuntu 13.04 x86_64

I don't have the reputation to make a new tag,so I used an existing one despite the fact it is not what I want

Comment: I have upgraded KeePassX to version 2.0 alpha 4
and using firefox web browser version 23

Comment: When I use auto type from the program window it works, but when I want to use the global auto type , it doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

Modify the launcher `keepassx.desktop` in `/usr/share/`

Replace: `Exec=keepasx %f`

With: `Exec=sh -c 'setxkbmap <keymap> && keepassx %f'`

Where `<keymap>` is the keymap you use (`fr, en-us, de, ...,` etc.).

Comment: have you tried this? This doesn't have anything to do with the problem